# Submitting information with a Rails form that is not accessible by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Looking for the "Rails convention" to do this:

I have a form for a model "user". The person filling out the form enters some information like "name" and "email", but some information is taken from the page due to other actions e.g. "upload_size".

Should I just create a hidden field in the user's form, and populate it with "upload_size"? Previously I had stored the info in JS, but I'm switching off of submitting the form via ajax.

Comment: don't know better option then creating a hidden field in user's form ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use a hidden field. That's what they're there for.